# How to get an AngularJS Expression to display nothing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have the following HTML:

```
<p>{{ booleanVariable ? "The variable is true!" : null }}</p>
```

If `booleanVariable` is false, the expression should be empty and the `<p></p>` shouldn't render. However, it just prints the "null" into the `<p>` tag, as if I'd just typed `<p>null</p>`.

How would I get the expression to just render nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty string is make sense.

```
<p>{{ booleanVariable ? "The variable is true!" : '' }}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `undefined` instead of `null`.

```
<p>{{ booleanVariable ? "The variable is true!" : undefined }}</p>
```

A simpler solution would be `ngShow`:

```
<p ng-show="booleanVariable">The variable is true!</p>
```

Comment: Using `ng-show` your element will be hidden which can be unwanted. (Example: element with css' paddings -- will break the layout). On the other hand, instead of null you can use `""` double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use

`<p ng-if="booleanVariable">The variable is true!</p>`

`ng-show` will have `<p>` in DOM but its just hidden if you use `ng-if` `<p>` will not be in DOM also